Market Making in practice
I read some of the papers in the market making literature such as: Avellaneda - Stoikov market making model but was wondering if these types of models are actually use in pratice?
It seems that when the number of assets traded grow then applying that type of models is difficult because of the curse of dimensionality.
Also I feel that these models are missing a lot. They always assume we have no alpha (predictive power of the mid-price) and basically just put bid/ask depending on the inventory. I feel that prop shop for example would have a less 'statistical way' of treating market making by doing client toxicity analysis for example (and skew the quote accordingly), having a bit of alpha and so on. So that at the end you can decompose the skewness of your quote in different component that are highly interpretable.
Hence I believe that using stochastic optimal control the way it's done in papers like Olivier Geant papers or Stoikov paper is not what is used in pratice in big MM firms like Citadel Securities, HRT and so on...
So my question is am I correct? and do you know any papers that have a different approach (a more practitioner approach) to making market making rather than using optimal stochastic control?

While academic models such as the Avellaneda-Stoikov market making model provide a theoretical framework for market making, they may not necessarily be directly applicable in practice. In practice, market making firms often use a combination of techniques, including client toxicity analysis, predictive analytics, and other proprietary strategies to optimize their market making activities.
Also, MMing nuances are different in different segments, e.g., equity, fixed income.

thank you for your response but you can provide more details. Like for example point out Reseach papers that actually develop these combinations of technics? like what type of theory is used to perform client toxicity, predictive analytics and so on? I don't think stochastic control is used for example

In client toxicity analysis, researchers may use techniques from market microstructure theory, which focuses on the dynamics of price formation and trading behavior in financial markets. By examining order flow data and trading patterns, researchers can analyze the impact of different types of orders on market liquidity and pricing.

For predictive analysis, one can use  time series analysis, regression analysis, and machine learning algorithms  to predict price changes and optimize strategies.

I will try to find some related papers.
